# FailedToUpdateEnpoint in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, linode

I have a kubernetes cluster with some deployments and pods.I have experienced a issue with my deployments with error messages like `FailedToUpdateEndpoint, RedinessprobeFailed`.

This errors are unexpected and didn't have idea about it.When we analyse the logs of our, it seems like someone try hack our cluster(not sure about it).

Thing to be clear:

1.Is there any chance someone can illegally access our kubernetes cluster without having the kubeconfig?

2.Is there any chance, by using the frontend IP,access our apps and make changes in cluster configurations(means hack the cluster services via Web URL)?

3.Even if the cluster access illegally via frontend URL, is there any chance to change the configuration in cluster?

4.Is there is any mechanism to detect, whether the kubernetes cluster is healthy state or hacked by someone?

Above three mentioned are focus the point, is there any security related issues with kubernetes engine.If not

Then,

5.Still I work on this to find reason for that errors, Please provide more information on that, what may be the cause for these errors?

Error Messages:

```
FailedToUpdateEndpoint: Failed to update endpoint default/job-store: Operation cannot be fulfilled on endpoints "job-store": the object has been modified; please apply your changes to the latest version and try again
```

The same error happens for all our pods in cluster.

```
Readiness probe failed: Error verifying datastore: Get https://API_SERVER: context deadline exceeded; Error reaching apiserver: taking a long time to check apiserver
```